# How to share a dynamically generated image from react with react-share?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, plotly.js, react-share

I have a react app which generates images on the front end dynamically using [Plotly.js](https://plotly.com/javascript/). I'd like to add image sharing functionality. I am trying to use [react-share](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share) for this. Social platforms require image URL for image sharing and do not support images in base64 encoding or alike. Backend was implemented so it can receive images in base64, store in the database and return URL to the image, which is then used for sharing with `react-share`.

As the image is generated dynamically (it changes each time user resizes the chart, for instance), everything should be done when user clicks on Share icon.

So after the user has clicked on the Share icon, the image generated on the front end should be saved to back end

```
let imgURI;

  const handleClick = () => {
    Plotly.toImage('chartContainer', {
      format: 'png',
      width: 1000,
      height: 600
    })
      .then(dataUrl => api.post('/image/base64ToPng', { image: dataUrl })
        .then(
          (response) => {
            imgURI = response.data.imgURI;
          },
          failure => console.error(failure)
        ));
  };
```

after the response is received, passed down to the sharing component like this

```
<FacebookShareButton
            url={imgURI}
          >
     <FacebookIcon/>
</FacebookShareButton>
```

The code sample is not asynchronous, so the image URI is not passed to the sharing component, therefore sharing does not work. I tried to pass the prop down using conditional depending on whether it's defined or not and did not come up with a solution. I also looked up [some](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/pull/336) [issues](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/issues/216) [in react-share repo](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/pull/268) that dealt with async urls, but seems like none of them deals with the dynamic image sharing on click.

I'd very appreciate a hint on how to complete this task.

Comment: Perhaps you could leverage useState (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)? const [imgURI, setImgURI] = useState();

And then inside your handleClick you do setImgURI(response.data.imgURI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is serious hack territory, and the whole thing would be a lot simpler if [this PR](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/pull/336) had been completed.

However, the code below should work (see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-url-sharing-sowl4?file=/src/App.tsx)).

The key steps are:

1. Have a bit of state that keeps track of whether you have a url from the service or not.
2. When this state is "none", disable the facebook button's default behavior (i.e. `openShareDialogOnClick` = `false`)
3. Add an `onClick` handler to the facebook button that asynchronously fetches the url and sets the state (triggering a re-render)
4. Use an effect + ref so that when the url is set to something real, you manually call the click event on the button (which now has a real address in its `url` prop), and then re-sets the url to "none"

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { FacebookIcon, FacebookShareButton } from "react-share";

async function getUrFromService(): Promise<string> {
  // The real implementation would make a network call here.
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  return "https://via.placeholder.com/150";
}

export default function App() {
  const shareButton = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string>("none"); // Unfortunately, we have to have a dummy string here, or FacebookShareButton will blow up.

  // Provide an onClick handler that asyncronously fetches the url and sets it in the state.
  const onClick = async () => {
    // Be sure to check for the "none" state, so we don't trigger an infinite loop.
    if (url === "none") {
      const newUrl = await getUrFromService();
      setUrl(newUrl);
    }
  };

  // Whenever "url" changes and we re-render, we manually fire the click event on the button, and then re-set the url.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (url !== "none") {
      shareButton.current?.click();
      setUrl("none");
    }
  }, [url, shareButton]);

  return (
    <FacebookShareButton
      ref={shareButton}
      // Disable calling the dialog if we don't have a url yet.
      openShareDialogOnClick={url !== "none"}
      url={url}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <FacebookIcon />
    </FacebookShareButton>
  );
}
```

Comment: And how to go on to share more than one image with the same use case?

Answer (score 1):

Use [navigator.share](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) api if possible.

Having, said that you could write a wrapper that manages loading state and disables icon of component.

Create a async share component

```
//AsyncShareLoader.jsx
const AsyncShareLoader = ({ url, children }) => {
  const loading = !url;
  return (
    <div style={{ filter: `grayscale(${loading ? "100%" : "0%"}` }}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          disabled: loading,
          url: loading ? "none" : url,
          openShareDialogOnClick: !loading
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, use this as a wrapper for your actual react-share icons. Something like this

```
const Share = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/imgUrl').then(getUrlFromRes).then(setUrl)
  }, [])

  return (
    <AsyncShareLoader url={url}>
      <FacebookShareButton>
        <FacebookIcon />
      </FacebookShareButton>
    </AsyncShareLoader>    
  );
}
```

Extending  this techinique you could manually steal click  as  Andrew suggested

Answer (score -1):

const getBase64ImageFromUrl = url =>
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(
blob =>
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
reader.onerror = reject;
blob = new Blob([blob], {type: 'image/png'});
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}),
);

const shareData = async () => {

```
await getBase64ImageFromUrl('https://url of image').then(base64 => {
  const shareOption = {
    title: App Link,
    url: base64,
    message:
      'Download app now: ,AppLink:""',
  };
  try {
    const shareResponse = Share.open(shareOption);
    console.log('share response ,', shareResponse);
  } catch (error) {
     alert(error.message);
  }
});
```

};